# EKS Error: You must be logged in to the server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I created EKS cluster via terraform:

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks-cluster" {
name     = "tf-example"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks_role.arn

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = var.subnet_ids
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks-cluster-policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks-cluster-security-group-policy
  ]
}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "eks-node-group" {
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.eks-cluster.name
  instance_types = var.instance_types
  node_group_name = "tf-example"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.eks-node-group.arn
  subnet_ids      = var.subnet_ids
  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 1
    max_size     = 1
    min_size     = 1
  }

  update_config {
    max_unavailable = 1
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks-node-group-worker-node-policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks-node-group-cni-policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks-node-group-registry-read-only-policy
  ]
}
```

The IAM roles and policies look like

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "eks_role" {
  name = "tf-${var.stack_name}-eks-cluster-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com",
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "eks-node-group" {
  name = "tf-${var.stack_name}-eks-node-group-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "eks.amazonaws.com",
          "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

When I run the aws eks update-kubeconfig --name cluster_name --region region_name

I get
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

I'm new to AWS and used to GCP. What policies does my user need? What role do I need to even run any kubectl command?

Comment: Which user was used to run the terraform? The user/role used to create the cluster is the admin of the cluster, you need to add any other user to the ConfigMap with Kubernetes, there the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html